# Xcode / iOS Automatic Delegate Assignment... A bug?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I found some unexpected behavior when debugging one of my table views.

[image: outlets are unset]

My tableView in the storyboard does not have its delegate or dataSource set.

[image: code snippet]

However, at the breakpoint in this snippet, both are set to the view controller.  I've checked my entire viewDidLoad hierarchy and at no point is the delegate set.

My question is: is this expected behavior? or is it a bug in Xcode or the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view Controller is a `UITableViewController`, then the delegate and data source of the table view it is the controller for is set to itself unless they are set in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was the behavior.